# Class yii\debug\Module does not exist after Update Composer

Tags: yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-basic-app

after Update Composer i have error Class yii\debug\Module does not exist

before run Update Composer my Gii , Debuger in Yii2 is Worked without any Problem.

my Composer.json in Root Yii2 Directory:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
    Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 8 updates, 53 removals
  - Removing bower-asset/typeahead.js (v0.11.1)
  - Removing bower-asset/jquery-ui (1.11.4)
  - Removing mrlco/yii2-jalali-datepicker (0.1.0)
  - Removing bower-asset/persian-datepicker (0.4.5)
  - Removing bower-asset/persian-date (0.1.8-patch1)
  - Removing codeception/specify (0.4.6)
  - Removing codeception/verify (0.3.2)
  - Removing codeception/base (2.2.8)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (5.7.9)
  - Removing myclabs/deep-copy (1.6.0)
  - Removing phpspec/prophecy (v1.6.2)
  - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (3.1.1)
  - Removing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.2.1)
  - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0)
  - Removing webmozart/assert (1.2.0)
  - Removing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.8)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (3.4.3)
  - Removing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
  - Removing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
  - Removing sebastian/object-enumerator (2.0.0)
  - Removing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0)
  - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (4.0.5)
  - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.2)
  - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
  - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.9)
  - Removing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.0)
  - Removing sebastian/environment (2.0.0)
  - Removing sebastian/version (2.0.1)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.3.1)
  - Removing psr/http-message (1.0.1)
  - Removing symfony/finder (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/console (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/debug (v3.2.2)
  - Removing psr/log (1.0.2)
  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/yaml (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/browser-kit (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/css-selector (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.2.2)
  - Removing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.3.0)
  - Removing behat/gherkin (v4.4.5)
  - Removing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4)
  - Removing sebastian/exporter (2.0.0)
  - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (2.0.0)
  - Removing sebastian/diff (1.4.1)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-faker (2.0.3)
  - Removing fzaninotto/faker (v1.6.0)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.0.5)
  - Removing phpspec/php-diff (v1.1.0)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.7)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-jui (2.0.6)
  - Removing yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.0.6)
  - Removing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.5)
  - Updating symfony/inflector (v3.2.8 => v3.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/property-access (v3.2.8 => v3.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/options-resolver (v3.2.8 => v3.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating endroid/qrcode (2.1.4 => 2.2.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.8.0 => v4.9.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (3.3.5 => 3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.11 => 2.0.11.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget (2.0.1 => 2.0.1): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: What exact command have you used to update composer packages? Have you tried to run update again?

Comment: Is there any solution?